# Update rows starting for specific number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a number into variable like:

```
DECLARE @CurrentLastFolio INT = (SELECT TOP 1 Folio FROM myTable ORDER BY folio DESC)
```

So supposing we have number `1004` into this variable.

Into another query I have some rows with `folio = 0`:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE folio = 0
```

That I want to do is to update this records with `@CurrentLastFolio + 1` on each row. So first row should have Folio = 1005, next 1006 and so on.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Are you looking to update a `folio` in your final query or add a new row with `folio = @CurrentLastFolio + 1`?

Comment: I want to update folio @RobeleBaker

Comment: So to understand correctly. You want to save the largest folio value in `myTable` and then update all `folio` values in `myTable`. I am assuming order is not preserved in your table. However, you want to update previously smallest `folio` value in `myTable` with the largest + 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```
 declare @CurrentLastFolio  int = (SELECT TOP 1 Folio from myTable  order by folio desc);

 with tbl AS 
 (
  SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( order by c1  )  AS rn 
  FROM myTable
 )
 update tbl set folio = rn + @x
```

---

Example Implementation for easy understanding

> ```
> create table t (c1 int);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into t values (1), (2), (3)
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> declare @x int = 1000;
>
> with tbl AS 
> (
>  SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER( order by c1  )  AS rn 
>  FROM t
> )
> update tbl set c1 = rn + @x 
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 3 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from t
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> |   c1 |
> | ---: |
> | 1001 |
> | 1002 |
> | 1003 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5cc5d9539d117d81dd13a8859c48c038)*

Comment: This update all folio numbers, I want to start update  where folio > @CurrentLastFolio so row number should start in 1005

Comment: I fix it as: `;WITH tbl AS 
 (
  SELECT * 
  ,@CurrentLastFolio + ROW_NUMBER() OVER( order by C1) AS rn 
  FROM t
  WHERE folio  = 0
 )
 update tbl set folio = rn `

Comment: @Jonathan - you should also get the same problem on numbers greater than 2,147,483,647. - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=32c7937f7530fcab1c9ba120057ca022

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following solution, updating the variable on the `UPDATE` too:

```
DECLARE @CurrentLastFolio INT = (SELECT MAX(folio) FROM table_name);

UPDATE table_name
    SET folio = @CurrentLastFolio, @CurrentLastFolio += 1 
WHERE folio = 0
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e80df91aad474019d6ba2afa1e6068fb)

---

**Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int:**

In case your values get larger than 2,147,483,647 (maximum value of `INT` data type) you need to use `BIGINT` intead of `INT` to store (column `folio`) or increment the value (variable `@CurrentLastFolio`):

```
-- you need to use BIGINT on the table.
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    folio BIGINT
)

-- you need to use BIGINT on the variable.
DECLARE @CurrentLastFolio BIGINT = (SELECT MAX(folio) from table_name);

-- now you can count and store numbers larger than INT maximum value.
UPDATE table_name
    SET folio = @CurrentLastFolio, @CurrentLastFolio += 1 
WHERE folio = 0
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=63dc6a8d0112a553c373aedec48ff41d)

Comment: It works!, but can you explain me why you use same sentence two times in SET clause? well one have `+` and other one have `+=` but how is that sentence called? I never seen that in update statement

Comment: @Jonathan - see the update. the first part (`folio = @CurrentLastFolio`) is updating the `folio` column. the second part updates the variable `@CurrentLastFolio`.

Comment: I try on sql but I get Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.